# Resize 2 parts of object with different ratio

Tags: dimensions

.

Hi all :)

I've an insole corresponding to a certain shoe size.
I need to resize this insole in order to have the right width for another shoe size.

[image]

The problem is that I've to resize (in x) the front and the back independently

[image]

For a specific case I need to increase front width by 12mm and back width by 4mm. But I need to keep an harmonious mesh.

Here's my blend file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47428

Do you have any idea? 
Thanks a lot

Maxime

Comment: **Proportional Editing** is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. :) I watched some video about this feature. But unfortunatly I'm not able to use it for my current example. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: steps]

Select vertices on both sides of the mesh, press <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd> > <kbd>LeftClick</kbd>. Then you can tweak settings in Tool Shelf (left side of the window - <kbd>T</kbd>) or by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the useful explanation. I tried it on an specific example and it worked :)
But I'm not sure that it can be precise enough to be used in a script for a generic solution.

Comment: @Maxime, well you didn't mentioned nothing about scripting this solution. I'm from artistic background and this is a method I would use for such task. There is another way with Lattice but I also don't see how it could be precise and generic at the same time. Maybe with simplified mesh and Subdivision Surface modifier it would be possible to script something like this. But in current form I think that Proportional Editing is your only choice.

Comment: Si answer acceptés. Thanks for you help :)